# Textures working in Blender 2.79, but not in Blender 2.80

Tags: texturing, uv

I understand that Blender 2.80 is in beta, but this seems like a glaring issue, so I imagine I must be doing something wrong here. I've been doing 3D modeling and animation on-and-off for the past 10 years (mostly in Maya or old crap like Strata 3D), but I'm *very* new to Blender itself.

I've downloaded a Blender model, but the textures don't appear to display properly. If you want to examine the file for yourselves, [here is its listing](https://sketchfab.com/models/65cc641a3adf42468641cc208a858187#download), and [here's a direct download link](https://sketchfab-prod-media.s3.amazonaws.com/archives/65cc641a3adf42468641cc208a858187/source/437c933d0de04b6a9ad25db9100977c4/sonic-hd-full-rigged.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAZ4EAQ242NI56GS4A&Expires=1548100707&x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEF0aDDK1%2B%2Ft07Y84lwdcLCK3A6DEmkIVhKG%2FRl3qbAA1CsZxZOzuvsW4OcWAiZ3Ob9nEJUg9SkMLegjymhqTnIORqHkHKoWMLcDFN2FMuSNP5rtIHBNFlmMNq5YwMUgNkfPUNEGrgHusuVMxm0k5%2BSHSdpCzZiLm9iQS6kxZQ4bdVr14JuocHEN7xqqUFgwR1W5SyBUlS4oS62V%2BIEIei0ZZVDnVZ%2FdbN4kbgC45e08XLnJGQX%2BCMFtjtw7p8vnv9eRcWPH5rVb5x1HPkEqLhSnbhdm4nNVmMO3hhnB2zJmp7znmgEpQ5M88V0JjElkQueKFK%2BqbsJmVnRPWqcNnoIESmWlbJh2ewMjKpHDhMJQhjRxZ8chVOrHeuCHjYdpS57FLGReybp7MUAg0qxL0Y5fD6FsdjxyYai1xrS%2FvpWleLnGcPn4mDXtwE3cr7qko9ajNtAafeNR3G%2FhxC9crOeLA5jle2qPq%2BgTme2wew1TOOECxEF0G4coFs6gIahXPK54R86Ds6sAWEqXH3qoiiiR3Vvw16ToTj7MPyheRrRU9QnnhhoLcfM7DKthI2RDVHUe51kXyd8ig9kV0ogltCFrasn1oxKAzdb8o8b2Y4gU%3D&Signature=gArqhsee6br7p0VeV%2B8ERbQWiA0%3D) (in case you don't want to make an account on that site).

Anyway, here's how it looks in Blender 2.79:
[image: 2.79]

2.79 Blender Internal Render:
[image: 2.79 Cycles]

Meanwhile, in Blender 2.80 Eevee:
[image: 2.80 Eevee]

And to make sure it's not an Eevee bug, here it is in 2.80 Cycles:
[image: 2.80 Cycles]

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious here. Any ideas what the issue might be? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I just realized that the 2.79 render was using Blender Internal, not Cycles. And when using Cycles on 2.79, we get essentially the same result as 2.80:
 [image: 2.79 Cycles]
So this may not be an issue specific to 2.80 after all. Have any of you encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Have you figured it out in 2.8 stable?